# New to tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, google-colaboratory

I want to learn tensorflow. I'm sorry for the questions but I learn In my own way. First, is there a list of definitions on terminology? Next, at my workplace we deal with a lot of flat files from different ecommerce sites. I want to build a bot that will do one of the following choices. I am not sure what is the best approach.

1. Teach it to write product descriptions based off product titles.
2. Teach it to write product titles and descriptions based off product images.

I am new to tensorflow not to all programming. I would like any ideas on where to start or what to read. Does anyone have a similar project that they are working on? Any input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am taking this [course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/introduction-tensorflow). I have taken a bunch of ml and nn courses that use tensorflow. This one is the easiest. It goes over using tensorflow and keras in a lot of detail using some mnist data sets.

There are a lot of cloud based courses. I recommend that you stay away from those until you get a good feeling for tensorflow.

There are a lot of videos about tensorflow. Start with those and then take the coursera course.